# How to read values from a text file and store them in different variable types in C

Tags: c, file

I need to read a text file with 7 lines into 7 different variables. The text file looks like this:

```
.2661
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
1
2
0.5 0.6
```

These are the variables that I need to store each line into:

```
float value1;             // line 1 from .txt file
char *AFileName;          // line 2 from .txt file
char *BFileName;          // line 3 from .txt file
char *CFileName;          // line 4 from .txt file
int value2;               // line 5 from .txt file
int lastLineLength;       // line 6 from .txt file
double lastLine[lastLineLength];    // line 7 from .txt file - this can be different lengths
```

I have currently been doing this by just using the arguments when I call my program from the command line and the argv command.

Comment: open the file, use `fgets` to read a line into a buffer and parse it like you did with `argv`.

Comment: Here's a hint: replace `argv[n]` with a call to `getParam(n, char *params[])`.  If `getParam` is defined as `char *getParam(int n, char *params[]) { return params[n] }`, how would you use that to read from argv[]?  And how would you use it to read from a file?

Comment: I am trying to change it so I do not use argv, I just included it to show what I have previously used. I need to change this code to just read from the file and not from the command line input.

Comment: What should happen if the line of input does not meet conversion requirements like trying to convert "xyz" into a `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the file using `fopen` with read access:

```
FILE *inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");
if(!inputFile) {
    // Error opening file, handle it appropriately.
}
```

Then read the data from the file using fscanf.  The first parameter is the `FILE *` we created above.  The second parameter is a format string that specifies what `fscanf` should expect while reading the file.  The remaining parameters are pointers to variables that will hold the data read from the file.

```
int variablesFound;
variablesFound = fscanf(inputFile, "%f\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n", &value1, AFileName, BFileName, CFileName, &value2, &lastLineLength);
if(variablesFound < 6) {
    // There was an error matching the file contents with the expected pattern, handle appropriately.
}

double lastLine[lastLineLength];

// Iterate over the last line.
int lastLineIndex;
for(lastLineIndex = 0; lastLineIndex < lastLineLength; lastLineIndex++) {
    fscanf(inputFile, "%lf", &lastLine[lastLineIndex]);
    fscanf(inputFile, " ");  // Eat the space after the double.
}
```

#### Edit

After comments I realized it might be worth noting that you have to allocate memory to your variables as the *real* first step.  The primitives (those with an `&` below) can be declared as normal.  For the string (char array), you'll want to do one of the following:

```
char *aFileName = calloc(MAX_FILENAME_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
```

or

```
char aFileName[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE + 1];
```

Depending on what your purpose with `aFileName` would be determines which method would be appropriate.  However, assuming this code appears in the `main` or doesn't need to exist beyond the scope of the function, the latter would be better as it doesn't require `free()`ing the variable after you're done with it.

It also may be worth while singling out the code that deals with reading input if your requirements change often.

Comment: Need allocate for `AFileName, BFileName, CFileName` in advance.

Comment: I keep getting a segmentation fault for AFileName.

Comment: I had to use char *AFileName = (char *)calloc(50, sizeof(char)); to allocate space for the 3 text files but this worked. Thank you.

Comment: @user3716193 or `char *AFileName;` --> `char AFileName[FILENAME_MAX+1];`

Comment: I assumed your variables were initialized beforehand.  If you use `*alloc()`, make sure to `free()` the memory once you no longer need it.  However, @BLUEPIXY's solution would probably be better in your case, where `FILENAME_MAX` is a macro `#define`d to be `50` (based on your last comment.

Comment: Note that `"%f%s%s%s%d%d"` and `"%f %s %s %s %d %d "` have similar results as `"%f\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n"` and are easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the file as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 80;

    fp = fopen("<path to your file>", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) 
        printf("%s", line);


    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

getline reads character strings from the file, so you'd have to parse the lines as needed (atoi, atof).

Comment: I'm not sure how to parse the values stored in line. I tried to use indexing like this: float rate = atof(&line[1]); but I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: try `atof(line)` for the first value, instead of `atof(&line)`. there's `&line` for getline because it's reading from the file and writing to the address of the variable. the string you want to use is actually `line`.

Comment: you'd also want to modify the above code to read from the file 7 times, instead of using a while loop to read till EOF, as the lines have different types.